# avr-gcc: Binary search vs. linear search

Tags: c, embedded, binary-search, avr-gcc, linear-search

I am searching in a few arrays of struct stored in program memory with lengths of about 30-200 with a linear search like this:

```
Glyph getGlyph(Font font, uint16_t code) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < font.length; i++) {
        if (pgm_read_word(&font.glyphs[i].code) == code) {
            static Glyph glyph;
            memcpy_P(&glyph, &font.glyphs[i], sizeof (Glyph));
            
            return glyph;
        }
    }
    
    // return question mark if unknown code point
    return getGlyph(font, 0x003f);
}
```

Assuming I am correctly reading the disassembly, there are 20 instructions per iteration, 3 of them rather expensive as far as I know: `brcc`, `brne` and `rjmp`.

Just evaluating if this could be done more (power) efficient, I implemented a binary search:

```
Glyph getGlyph(Font font, uint16_t code) {
    
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm
    int16_t l = 0;
    int16_t r = font.length - 1;
    
    while (l <= r) {
        uint8_t m = (l + r) / 2;
        uint16_t c = pgm_read_word(&font.glyphs[m].code);
        if (c < code) {
            l = m + 1;
        } else if (c > code) {
            r = m - 1;
        } else {
            // found code point, get and return glyph
            static Glyph glyph;
            memcpy_P(&glyph, &font.glyphs[m], sizeof (Glyph));
            
            return glyph;
        }
    }
    
    // return question mark if unknown code point
    return getGlyph(font, 0x003f);
}
```

This results in 35 instructions per iteration in the disassembly, of which 5 are what I think rather expensive: `brlt`, `brcc` (2x) and `rjmp` (2x).

Given that the arrays are rather short, I suppose the benefit of the binary search is not a lot and might be compensated by the increased complexity?

Is it worth or does it make sense at all trying to benchmark this?

The program is compiled with `-Os`. Compiling with `-O3` instead as suggested in comments, it seems the amount of instructions is a multiple, but maybe I am just not interpreting the disassembly correctly.
It is running on an ATmega328p and I'm currently building it with gcc 5.4.0 and avr-libc 2.0. I tried also with gcc 13 and avr-libc 2.1 but I find the disassembly quite hard to read.

This is just a [simple thermometer and hygrometer with an e-ink display](https://github.com/gitdode/thermidity), it runs well and I am satisfied with speed and power consumption, though I lack experience and can't compare with anything else. I'm really just curious and want to learn.

Comment: We get a worse case of 20 * 100 = 2000 instructions with first approach, and 35 * log2(100) = 245 instructions with the second.

Comment: Tip: Not an issue here, but `(l + r) / 2` can also be written as `l + ( l - r ) / 2` to avoid overflows.

Comment: I assume you do build with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, with `-Os`

Comment: I wonder if [this](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/00d9de13023d70bd681be811daabcc62) might be a *tiny* bit better on average. (Replaces `r` and `l` with a pointer and size.)

Comment: That optimizes for size, not speed. If you use `-O3` you will probably get better code. Perhaps even small enough code to satisfy whatever size requirements you might have.

Comment: The question is about optimizing for speed, but `-Os` optimizes for space. `-O3` would make more sense.

Comment: What microcontroller you are using?

Comment: Using `-O3` for AVR usually mostly bloats code without making it recognizably faster. Benchmarking different solutions makes always sense when you are after best performance.

Comment: What's the range of `code`? Is it really full swing of `uint16_t` or something more constrained?

Comment: Also: What exact AVR are you using. Which version of C/C++ and which version of avr-gcc/avr-g++?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts A uint8_t would actually be enough (only using UTF-8 code points U+0000 to U+00FF). I included gcc and avr-libc versions in the question.

Comment: If `code` fits in 8 bits, then maybe lookup-table is a viable approach? Per font it requires 256 bytes.  And the font / glyph addresses must be known at link-time.

Comment: Just use `Glyph* pGlyphs[256];` followed by `memcpy_P(&glyph, pGlyphs[(uint8_t)code], sizeof (Glyph));`.

Comment: @ikegami Your comment "We get a worse case of 20 * 100 = 2000 instructions..." is a good answer to my question I think - so why don't you make it an answer?
I appreciate all the other comments and suggestions a lot - but my question really was about binary vs. linear search in this scenario :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of big bottlenecks in this program and they aren't necessarily related to the searching as such. To address them you'll rather need a code review:

- Why are you passing structs etc by value? That's extremely inefficient on 8 bitters, even in case of small structs.
- When you return a glyph, you first copy it from somewhere (flash) into the `static` variable (.bss) and then copy it again onto the function call stack and then finally you copy it again in the caller. This is massively inefficient when you could just have returned a `const` pointer pointing at the original item, or alternatively if these need to be modified in run-time, just copy it *once* - probably still return a `const` pointer and let the caller copy the data.

  (Might be necessary to use some Harvard architecture tweaks to access flash data directly - whatever your compiler uses to handle that, "PROGMEM" macro or some such.)
- Avoid needlessly large counters and indices. If you don't plan to go beyond value 255 then don't use `uint16_t`. And pretty much never use `size_t` which will be a 32 bit type and therefore horribly slow.
- Recursive functions should pretty much never be used in any context and certainly never in embedded systems. That part must be rewritten as a loop - I don't even understand why you are using recursion at all.
- Using standard lib `bsearch` is not necessarily that much slower than rolling out your own version manually. Benchmark with an oscilloscope.
- In general, binary search is a pretty sound algorithm for 8-bitters. We neither need to worry about branching nor alignment, just the raw amount of instructions generated. On the other hand you literally picked one of the slowest CPUs still in production, so why worry about performance.

Overall I think you would benefit from picking a modern MCU instead, such as a Cortex M. Programming old 8-bitters in C is actually pretty hard and it's easy to make mistakes. AVR is 1990s technology, there's not many reasons for using them any longer. (They are a pretty good choice for learning assembler but that's about it.)

Comment: Why do you say `size_t` is 32 bit? I would assume it is 16 bit. "Programming old 8-bitters in C is actually pretty" Not really. It is easier than programming Applications for an OS.

Comment: I'm not surprised my code can be improved; I'm used to OO programming on systems with lots of CPUs and RAM, and this is just a hobby project. I'll try to pass structs by reference instead (I read about some votes against it though) and `pgm_read_word` and `memcpy_P`already is about handling Harvard architecture, I'm actually glad it all works as expected :-) And I guessed already the recursive call is horrible...
I only know AVR MCUs (and a litte bit of C); I like both and the AVRs already can do way more than I need. I just want to learn a bit and have some fun.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 It is most often the same size as long on 8 bit MCUs since they often come with a flavour of extended addressing beyond 64kb. Though maybe AVR is so damn old that they never even got around to that - if so it would be 16 bit indeed.

Comment: @TorstenRömer In addition to all that's been said, check the compiler docs for how they ABI and calling convention is defined for this port. You'll soon discover why structs is a bad idea, typically just 2-3 CPU registers are used at most, if at all. The rest goes onto the precious stack.

Comment: @Lundin Aren't registers also precious on these MCUs? I have ~90% of free RAM, so it should be okay to use some stack space?

Comment: @TorstenRömer The best practice is to never push structs by value on the stack even on the most high-end CPUs, because there's never a reason to. How much RAM you have is irrelevant, how big is the stack?

Comment: @Lundin It is most likely 16 bit, see here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc

Comment: @Lundin The stack seems to share remaining RAM with heap: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html
But anyway, I fully take your point and will try to pass structs by reference instead of value.

Comment: So I am hopefully correctly passing all structs by reference now and already I can tell the `getGlyph` function only needs 45 instead of 77 instructions. That's quite a lot I would say.

Comment: @TorstenRömer If you have a heap on an AVR, something in your linker script has gone terribly, terribly wrong. Similarly, having the stack and the heap grow into each other as shown on that questionable link is madness. The ideal setup if possible is to have the stack grow into an area where it can cause no harm, such as non-mapped memory. You can also place canaries along the way and poll those regularly.

Comment: @Lundin I don't use a linker script, I'm just building with `avr-gcc` and trust in the default RAM layout. If you think this wrong or the official avr-libc documentation is wrong, maybe you could contribute to improve it?

Comment: @TorstenRömer There will always be a linker script, whether you invoke it implicitly or not. And I wouldn't waste my time contributing to ancient technology open source projects... It is bad enough that I still have to maintain a lot of products containing 8-bitters. The sooner these die out, the better, far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry to hear you are unhappy with these projects and I know it can be unpleasant having to work with old stuff. So I appreciate even more you took the time to contribute to my question (and thus, to my project using old technology).

Answer (score 1):

After checking your github project and after you provided the constraints (ATmega328p) I think I understood your issue.

You have to conserve every bit of your precious 2048 bytes RAM of this ATmega. Placing a `lookuptable[256]` in RAM is no option due to available memory.

Transform your font table to this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t height;    /* Height of all glyphs of this font. */
    Glyph Glyphs[256]; /* Glyphs for all 256 charcodes*/
} newFont; /*sitting in PROGMEM*/
```

After the data prepared for use in that way, the final `getGlyph()` becomes an one-liner:

```
void getGlyph(Glyph *pDest, newFont const/*PROGMEM*/ * pFont, uint8_t code)
{
    memcpy_P(pDest, pFont->Glyphs[code], sizeof(*pDest));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any issue (besides my code is probably quite inefficient): RAM usage is 200 bytes (9.8%) and my question was about binary vs. linear search (I want to learn about that). I have two fonts: Unifont with ~200 chars and Dejavu with 28 chars or so. So I'd need two Glyph[] arrays with at least as many as the highest code point elements plus quite some 'placeholders', right?

Comment: I am afraid the speed comparison between linear or binary search is not an issue to your actual project. Again, I suggest to use a simple lookup table with exact 256 entries for each font. You can safely go in it with a 8 bit unsigned char value as index and you are done. Faster than any search.

Comment: Is a lookup table with 256 entries efficient when only 28 elements are needed?

Comment: This is a usual execution time - used memory trade-off. And yes, a table[256] with only 28 used elements is a waste of memory. But they are sitting in your 32KB FLASH. I assume you have plenty of space there.

Comment: Also true. But for the time being, I like the "pass structs by reference + binary search" variant best. I am trying as good as I can to benchmark and compare all variants.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after fast code, a lookup-table may be the way to go.

There are two flavours.  The code below stands in GNU-C99 so that the `__flash` qualifier is supported.  This allow more comprehensible code that's not cluttered up with `pgm_read_xxx`. If you stick with `pgm_read_xxx`, you'll have to translate the code.

Also the code uses *pointers* intead of copying `Font`'s and `Glyph`'s back and forth.  The complete, with avr-gcc v5.4 compileable code follows at the end of the answer.

## Lookup-Table in Flash

This is the preferred way to go as it does not require precious RAM.  The code below assumes that the lookup table is initialized with `0`, which is the default for data in static storage.  So when we read an id of `0`, we have to check whether is's actually `glyph[0]` that's correct, or some default like glyph with `code = '?'`

```cpp
const __flash Glyph*
getGlyph_lookup_flash (const __flash Font *font, uint8_t code)
{
    uint8_t id = font->lookup_flash[code];
    // 0 is also the default initializer value for data in static storage.
    // Check whether we found glyph[0] or not.
    if (id == 0 && code != font->glyphs[0].code)
        id = font->lookup_flash['?'];

    return & font->glyphs[id];
}
```

**Notes:**

- If you manage to initialize all unused entries of `.lookup_flash` with the id of `?`, the `if` instruction is no more necessary.
- If you are using just one font, then `font->glyphs[0].code` is known at compile-time. In the sample code at the end of the answer, it could be replaced with `'a'`.
- As you wrote in a comment, code fits in `uint8_t`, hence each font will cost additional 256 bytes of program memory.

## Lookup-Table in RAM

This is an alternative approach when lookup-tables in program memory are not feasible for some reason.  I am actually using this approach with ATmega168/328 for a vector font with variable glyph sizes, where a lookup table in flash is just too painful to pre-compute.  When you basically are using codes from 0x20 to 0x7f (ASCII) with some exceptions, then you can handle exceptions by hand and thus reduce the table size to, say, 0x60 bytes.

The code uses the same lookup with different fonts. If a font-switching is detected, the table is reset. For unknown entries, a linear search is used to find the glyph and its id.

```cpp
#define INVALID_ID 0xff

typedef struct
{
    const __flash Font *pfont;
    uint8_t code_to_id[0x100];
} lookup_t;

static void init_lookup (uint8_t *p)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        *p++ = INVALID_ID;
    } while (++i);
}

const __flash Glyph*
getGlyph_lookup_ram (const __flash Font *font, uint8_t code)
{
    static lookup_t lookup_ram;

    // Unknown font: Reset `lookup_ram'.
    if (font != lookup_ram.pfont)
        init_lookup (lookup_ram.code_to_id);

    uint8_t *pid = & lookup_ram.code_to_id[code];

    if (*pid != INVALID_ID)
        // Known id.
        return & font->glyphs[*pid];

    // Unknown id: Do a linear search for glyph with required .code.
    const __flash Glyph *pglyph = & font->glyphs[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < font->length; ++i, ++pglyph)
    {
        if (pglyph->code == code)
        {
            *pid = i;
            return pglyph;
        }
    }
    
    // Return question mark if unknown code point.
    pglyph = getGlyph_lookup_ram (font, '?');

    // id for code is unknown. Set it to id of '?' so that the next time
    // we don't have to search all glyphs again.
    *pid = lookup_ram.code_to_id['?'];

    return pglyph;
}
```

## Compileable Code for avr-gcc v5.4

Finally, here is the complete compile-able example for reference and in
[godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zf7TY14oT)

I added boilerplate definitions for `Font` and `Glyph`.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t code;
    uint8_t data[4];
} Glyph;

typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    Glyph glyphs[4];
    uint8_t lookup_flash[0x100];
} Font;

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) (sizeof (X) / sizeof (*X))

const __flash Font font1 =
{
    .length = ARRAY_SIZE (font1.glyphs),
    .glyphs =
    {
        [0] = { 'a', { 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa } },
        [1] = { 'B', { 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB } },
        [2] = { '2', { 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22 } },
        [3] = { '?', { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67 } },
    },
    .lookup_flash =
    {
        ['a'] = 0,
        ['B'] = 1,
        ['2'] = 2,
        ['?'] = 3,
    }
};

const __flash Glyph*
getGlyph_lookup_flash (const __flash Font *font, uint8_t code)
{
    uint8_t id = font->lookup_flash[code];
    // 0 is also the default initializer value for data in static storage.
    // Check whether we found glyph[0] or not.
    if (id == 0 && code != font->glyphs[0].code)
        id = font->lookup_flash['?'];

    return & font->glyphs[id];
}

#define INVALID_ID 0xff

typedef struct
{
    const __flash Font *pfont;
    uint8_t code_to_id[0x100];
} lookup_t;

lookup_t lookup_ram;

static void init_lookup (uint8_t *p)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        *p++ = INVALID_ID;
    } while (++i);
}

const __flash Glyph*
getGlyph_lookup_ram (const __flash Font *font, uint8_t code)
{
    // Unknown font: Reset `lookup_ram'.
    if (font != lookup_ram.pfont)
    {
        init_lookup (lookup_ram.code_to_id);
        lookup_ram.pfont = font;
    }

    uint8_t *pid = & lookup_ram.code_to_id[code];

    if (*pid != INVALID_ID)
        // Known id.
        return & font->glyphs[*pid];

    // Unknown id: Do a linear search for glyph with required .code.
    const __flash Glyph *pglyph = & font->glyphs[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < font->length; ++i, ++pglyph)
    {
        if (pglyph->code == code)
        {
            *pid = i;
            return pglyph;
        }
    }
    
    // Return question mark if unknown code point.
    pglyph = getGlyph_lookup_ram (font, '?');

    // id for code is unknown. Set it to id of '?' so that the next time
    // we don't have to search all glyphs again.
    *pid = lookup_ram.code_to_id['?'];

    return pglyph;
}

int main (void)
{
    const __flash Glyph *pglyph1 = getGlyph_lookup_flash (&font1, '*');
    const __flash Glyph *pglyph2 = getGlyph_lookup_ram (&font1, 'B');

    // If you actually need the glyph in RAM, you can:
    Glyph glyph = *pglyph1;
    glyph = *pglyph2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, I really appreciate it and will try to understand and use the information given by you to improve. But again, this is just a hobby project, it is not used to control the cooling system of a nuclear power station. It is just supposed to work well and it actually does that, probably thanks to the compiler that somehow seems to make something efficient out of my clumsy code.

Comment: Hobby projects also deserve their dedication.

Comment: Please don't tell me I'm not dedicated - I'm putting a lot of passion into this.

Comment: Oh, I obviously picked the wrong words, sorry for that, I am not a native speaker. I just wanted to say that IMHO it's absolutely fine to put work into hobby projects.

Comment: All is fine, thanks. I am not a native speaker myself :-) If you have a look at the project on GitHub, then you'll hopefully see that I am putting a lot of time in it, probably more than I should... it includes many aspects and I'm trying handle all of them as good as I can. I have just started to try and optimize the code.